# Trying to obtain cookies with PHP's CURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm just trying to obtain some cookies from a website using curl, I've read thousands of topics related with this, the problem was in almost every case related to the path to the file (which must be absolute).

I tried several things but I can not find the reason why my cookies are not being written. Here I go with the code:

```
$cookieDir = 'tmp/cookies.txt';

$options = Array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => realpath($cookieDir),
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => realpath($cookieDir)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
ob_start();
$data = curl_exec($ch);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close($ch);
```

Some annotations:

1. The file exists
2. realpath($cookieDir) is writable
3. I'm getting the website in $data without troubles

Thank you guys

Comment: You can use the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option and then check the result for cookies using something like: `preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^\r\n]*)/mi', $data, $cookies);`

Comment: Your cookieDir variable is not absolute.. it's not starting with a `/` or `C:\` for Windows

Comment: I didn't even know how cookies where sent, that's an advance. Now I found something rare that might be causing the whole thing. I get the header with CURLOPT_HEADER = true but it does not contain the cookies. They should be there, I can see them in the header in Firebug

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set the `CURLOPT_POST` option to true to get the cookies, the following worked for me:

```
$cookieDir = '<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/cookie.txt';

$options = array ( 
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
   CURLOPT_URL => '<URL>',
   CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookieDir,
   CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookieDir,
   CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

You should also be able to get all cookies from the header by setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` in your request:

```
$cookieDir = '<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/cookie.txt';

$options = array (
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
   CURLOPT_URL => '<URL>',
   CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
   CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$data = curl_exec($ch);  
// check the return value for `Set-Cookie` header
$cookies = array();
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^\r\n]*)/mi', $data, $cookies); 
// $cookies[0] now contains any `Set-Cookie:` header
```

Comment: Looks like is the culprit is the target website, I tried with another site receiving correctly the cookies, I can confirm that POST parameter is not necessary. Do you have any idea why do this happen? I tried putting CURLOPT_USERAGENT to "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0" but it stills sends me nothing :(

Comment: I've made it :_) I'll post the answer in a moment. Thank you, I couldn't have done without knowing how the cookies were sent

Comment: I tried with and without post and only got it to work with post set to true, but I also think this can be depending on the website.

Answer (score 0):

It was the website who was not allowing me to get their cookies, to get them I had to made it think I'm a ordinary browser using this extra parameter:

```
$header = array (
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Connection: keep-alive'
);
```

Then in $options

```
$options = array (
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => realpath($cookieDir),
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => realpath($cookieDir),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
);
```

Even though its a strange case I hope it will help others =)